# Consulta otros registros mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo los siguientes datos en una tabla pivote,

```
estado| tipo
libre | moto
libre | camioneta
libre | furgón
en uso| moto
libre | bicicleta
en uso| camioneta
```

tengo hasta ahora solo la consulta básica, he intentado de todas maneras pero no logro dar con el resultado, estoy usando Laravel 5.4, pero mientras estoy haciendo pruebas con phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM `cometido_vehiculo` WHERE estado = 0
```

y necesito obtener los tipos que estén libres es decir "Furgón y bicicleta"
cuando hago la consulta igual me arroja el siguiente resultado "moto,camioneta,furgón,bicicleta"
alguna idea?
Edite la pregunta anterior porque no me supe explicar bien,
saludos

Comment: pero si el unico id abierto es el 4, estaras queriendo armar la consulta al reves?

Comment: si, esos datos fueron de ejemplo, el tema fundamental de la consulta es que como puedo hacer para mostrar el resto de los valores y no mostrar uno que esté "abierto y cerrado" (como es el caso del id 1 y 3 en la tabla de enmedio)

Comment: Ten en cuenta que no sabemos que ves vos. Si nos mostras esos datos y ese resultado, suponemos que algo esta mal. Las preguntas tienen que dejarnos reproducir el problema.

Comment: si, lo siento, no supe explicarme bien.. voy a editar la pregunta

Comment: Puedes mostrar lo has realizado hasta ahora

Comment: tengo solo la consulta básica, estoy realizando pruebas en phpmyadmin. Edité mi pregunta.

Comment: @Renato si trabajas en **Laravel**, es un framework muy muy util y uno muy utilizado ultimamente, deberias de ver: [eloquent el orm de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) que una herramienta muy util para tus consultas, no necesitas saber `sql` para hacer consultas, ademas deberias de publicar las tres tablas y mejorar tu pregunta, ya que es poco entendible.

Comment: Renato con las ediciones dejaste peor que antes la pregunta. Necesitas mostrarnos los datos de todas las tablas involucradas, y decirnos como se relacionan entre si, y un ejemplo claro de los datos que quieres obtener.

Comment: @Renato, puedes mostrar como están las tablas enlazadas, Dices que el estado es libre pero luego lo realizas por el id que supongo que será del estado. Muestra las tablas y sus campos como el tipo de dato de cada campo para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas una subconsulta, usa:

```
SELECT * FROM 'cometido_vehiculo' where tipo not in (SELECT distinct tipo from `cometido_vehiculo` WHERE estado = 'en uso')
```

Según tu query de ejemplo quizás debas reemplazar *estado = 'en uso'* por *estado=1*
Espero te sirva. Suerte

Comment: Gracias! era esto lo que necesitaba, no sabia como expresar bien la pregunta , saludos

Comment: si esta usando larave 5.4, su consulta no es la mas obtina, hay una funcion llamada with("llave_forania")->get();